# Tensorflow: How to define custom metrics for LSTM stock prediction model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a stock price prediction model using lstm. It is very rare that the predicted price and the actual stock price match exactly, so I tried to calculate the accuracy by dividing the number of predictions that came within a certain range(ex. 3%) by a total number of predictions.

I thought accuracy calculations were calculated at the end of each epoch. Here's what I intend:

```
def acc (y_true, y_pred):
    correc_num = 0
    correc_range = 0.03
    
    for i in range(len(y_pred)):
        if (y_true[i] * (1-correc_range) <= y_pred[i])  and  (y_pred[i] <= y_true[i] * (1+correc_range)):
            correc_num += 1

    return correc_num / len(y_pred) * 100
```

And of course, it didn't work, and I realize it should be calculated as tensor.
When I print y_true, the result was:
`Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)`

I rewrite the code:

```
def acc (y_true, y_pred):
    correc_range = 0.03

    correc_min = tf.fill(y_ture.shape, 1 - correc_range)
    correc_max = tf.fill(y_ture.shape, 1 + correc_range)

    correc num = torch.sum(tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(y_pred, correc_min), tf.less_equal(y_pred, correc_max)))
    
    return correc_num / len(y_pred) * 100
```

But I couldn't find the substitution for `len(y_pred)`.

How should I change `len(y_pred)`?

Am I doing right???

Comment: Why do you want to use accuracy for a regression task? Wouldn't you be better using RMSE or other typical regression metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

First of all, never mix `pytorch` and `tensroflow`, it's good for your hardware, your program and also your health, to use just one of those.

#### Hacky Solution

You can use `tf.shape(y_pred)` and extract the dimension you are looking for (should be the dimension 0 - `tf.shape(y_pred)[0]`).

You can also exploit the fact that `y_true` and `y_pred` share the `batch_size` dimension, so you can just reduce the dimensions of your vectors:

```py
...
correc_num = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.lofical_and(...), 'float32'), axis=0)

return correc_num / tf.reduce_mean(y_pred, axis=0) * 100
```

Note that `reduce_mean` needs float typed tensors.

## Smarter Solution

By the way I warmly invite you to **read carefully** the [Tensorflow Metrics Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics) because there are many metrics already implemented and usually you can achieve what you want just by using one of them (or either by combining them). Usually **RMSE** or **MAE** are the way for regression models.